# Database Management for Apache Cassandra 3.5

Tags: cassandra, opscenter, cassandra-3.0

Anyone know any good open source database management tool like Opscenter for Apache Cassandra? Opscenter only work for Apache Cassandra version 2.1 below but we are using Apache Cassandra version 3.5 so Opscenter wont work. Thanks Phuong